# How to query Maven repository from application to obtain metadata

Tags: maven

I'm trying to migrate an eclipse project to a maven projet. The eclipse project refernces  many jars in its .classpath file.
I'm looking for a way to generate the corresponding pom dependencies.

Say I have Velocity-3.1.jar, I want my app generate corresponding XML chunk :

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>Apache-velocity</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

The app was able to query some service and found the groupId, artefactId, version data.

Of course, I accept errors and will check the generated metadata.

Is there some Maven service/plugin which would do the trick ?

many thanks !

Comment: Best thing is to use the search capabilities of Maven central (http://search.maven.org) and do it by hand. How many jars do you have ?

Comment: I have 15 projects with 10-15 jars /project :(

Comment: May be some scripting could do the majority of the job...with hand reviewing the results.

Comment: In fact I was thinking of the following course : 
// Parse each project folder and retrieve the .classpath file, for each file retrieve the name of the jars with XPath.

// for each jar, split it, using the last - as the version separator

// for each jar, submit it to the desired service.

This is where I stuck. I thought of some kind of web service, since it is not available, maybe code some parser of the result page of the repo maven search engine. 

In fact, I wanted to avoid coding the parser.

Comment: Have you taken a deep look at this: http://search.maven.org/#api There exist a REST API

Comment: How can I close the question and vote it ?

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise for the link to search.maven.org  Oddly Google wasn't suggesting that for the searches I was trying.

Comment: One hint on search.maven.org: If it's not finding something you're looking for, it might be a non-open source tool that's only deployed inside your company's private repository.  For example, I think this is why I can't find any Oracle Coherence stuff.  Of course Oracle isn't open source, but I was assuming that some parts of Coherence were since I saw it in our pom.xml files AND pom files that I found on Google.  But I suspect in all cases those were deployed to a local repo behind a firewall.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't find the download count within the API, can someone share a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the maven central repository API.

Have a look to the official page: http://search.maven.org/#api

HIH
M.

Comment: Too bad it's not available from a javascript webapp because of CORS.

Answer (score 5):

Official page for maven central repository API is changed. Here is the new url

https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/

Comment: This is new one: https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide/

Comment: Any API which tells the jar is vulnerable or not ?

Comment: @Kiran, based on my research, there are no publicly available ones. There are, however, commercial solutions that provide this service.